# How do I convert String to Long with two significant digits in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to get 123456789.12 value out of 123456789.1234

If i use strings, it will be worked straightaway using parsing logic. I don't want to return String. requirement is to return Long.

Here i would like return the output the Long type rather than string..can someone help me on this?

Comment: Long is an integer type so you can't return any decimals at all.

Answer (score 3):

Long is an integer type, and thus can not hold a decimal. 
Trying to use Long.parseLong would result in a `NumberFormatException`.
You need to use a representation that deals with the scale as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this for long output:

```
String str = "123456789.1234";
BigInteger num = new BigInteger(str);

return num.longValue();
```

try this for float output:

```
String str = "123456789.1234";
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(str).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

return num.floatValue();
```

Comment: BigInteger and BigDecimal should be used if you are dealing with currency calculation..

Comment: Did you try running this code? The first part throws exception, and second doesnt do what the question asks

Answer (score 0):

The number which you want to return it is not Long.You can return double or float.Also you can use

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String stringDouble = df.format(yourDouble);;
```

Comment: This code will not give the desired output for ex. 1.3799 should return 1.38

Comment: if you want to get 123456789.12 from 123456789.1234 code give result

Comment: ohh sorry result is String and you can parse to double